# Set defaultDate in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used datepicker to create a widgets to select date. What I want to do is to set `defaultDate` to the date that is already computed (`dd,mm,yy`). How can I do this?

```html
<div class="datediv">
  <input type="text" name="dd_signature_date" value="<%=dd%>"> /
  <input type="text" name="mm_signature_date" value="<%=mm%>"> /
  <input type="text" name="yy_signature_date" value="<%=yy%>"> /
</div>
<div class="datediv">
  <input type="text" name="dd_date" value="<%=dd%>"> /
  <input type="text" name="mm_date" value="<%=mm%>"> /
  <input type="text" name="yy_date" value="<%=yy%>"> /
</div>
<div class="datediv">
  <input type="text" name="dd_start_date" value="<%=dd%>"> /
  <input type="text" name="mm_start_date" value="<%=mm%>"> /
  <input type="text" name="yy_start_date" value="<%=yy%>"> /
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("div.datediv").children().datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var pieces = dateText.split('/');

      if ($j(this) attr("name").includes("dd")) {
        $j(this).val(pieces[1]);
        $j(this).next().val(pieces[0]);
        $j(this).next().next().val(pieces[2]);
      }
      if ($j(this) attr("name").includes("mm")) {
        $j(this).prev().val(pieces[1]);
        $j(this).val(pieces[0]);
        $j(this).next().val(pieces[2]);
      }

      if ($j(this) attr("name").includes("yy")) {
        $j(this).prev().prev().val(pieces[1]);
        $j(this).prev().val(pieces[0]);
        $j(this).val(pieces[2]);
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: The way you've used three individual fields for the date makes the entire point of a datepicker completely pointless...

Comment: `<input type="date" />` <--

Comment: I can't make  changes to this code. The only things I have to resolve the problem are  those you see